# match multiple occurrences, regex javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

i want to find all occurrences of `[anything-here]` in sentence

I `[am]` John. `[yesterday morning]` я `[русский]` and Georgian `[ქართული]` and Indian `[utf8-chars]` and with symbols or space `[good morning]` or `[hello, how are you?]`

the result must be
`[am]`
`[yesterday morning]`
`[русский]`
`[ქართული]`
etc.

Thanks

Comment: Please provide more context as it is very unclear what do you want to achieve

Comment: ]Happy to hear you:re looking for those occurences. I'm pretty sure regexp can find them. I guess any available regexp resource would tell you how. This site is not a real-time Q&A forum. It's not designed to answer questions that you could easily answer yourself with a bit of research. That's why people are downvoting. You might want to close this question before your reputation incurs more damage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var match = myString.match(/\[.+?\]/g);
```

Technically, this code will match all sentences between `[` and `]`

Comment: I don't think the actual text will contain brackets around the words he's looking for. But let's hope that it will!

Comment: In is example and is result he is looking for text between brackets :)
But you are right, I doesn't explain clearly what he wants.

Comment: in the sentence [this part must be omitted]. so i want to find what words are thought to be omitted in sentence

Comment: Why does the closing `]` need escaping?

Comment: Because the opening `[` is also escaping ? 
`[` and `]` are reserved char in regexp that's why we need to escape them if we want to find them.